# Are there any reasons not to extend std::set to add a subscript operator?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdset, extending-classes

I'm using `std::set` to store unique instances of a class. `std::set` does not have an overloaded subscript operator so you can't do `set[0]` for example.

I found a way to do it:

```
auto myClass = *std::next(set.begin(), index);
```

However, I found it monotonous to copy that code over and over again. So I decided it would be much more convenient to just extend `std::set` (`class sset`) and just overload the subscript operator in it.

```
template <class T>

class sset: public std::set<T>
{
public:
    T operator[](const uint32_t i) const
    {
        if(i <= (this->size()-1))
            return *std::next(this->begin(), i);
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Index is out of range");
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto myClass = set[0]; //works and no exception thrown

    return 0;
}
```

I achieved the desired behavior but it occurred to me that there must have been a reason the standard didn't include a subscript operator. Surely not just laziness.

Is there any preceived disadvantage or possible future problems one can see doing this?

Comment: A subscript overload makes sense for associate types like `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` because it mimics the behavior of an array, just using an arbitrary key type instead of an integer index. But sets don't hold key/value pairs, they just hold keys. How is `someset["a"]` supposed to work? You can't assign to it because there's no value associated with that key. What it's supposed to return? Again, no value... It doesn't make sense. Thus, no subscript overloads.

Comment: This is a `set`, right? That means items in the container do not have a *fixed* index. That is, `set[2]` may become a different object simply by inserting an element into the set. So why exactly do you need to index a set by numeric indices like this?

Comment: Note that the container classes in C++ are not designed to be publicly inherited from anyway. If you really want to use such a special set container (which is a bad idea to begin with, see all the answers), then you should privately inherit from `std::set` or use a data member to which you delegate all required operations.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: `std::stack` and `std::queue`, with protected members, are clearly designed to be inherited from. I know there is a misguided notion floating around that public inheritance is contra-indicated when there is not a virtual destructor. Perhaps that's what you're referring to?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: But you don't need public inheritance to access them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, I'm refering to the "misguided" notion that classes without virtual functions are usually not meant to be publicly inherited from.

Comment: One can't (rationally) infer intent from such features. And even where there is a known intent, it should have no bearing on one's technical decisions. Unless one is hopelessly mired in authority argumentation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Now you are playing the devil's advocate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indexing should never be more than logarithmic time, that's what's expected. This indexing is (at least) linear time. That's awfully inefficient. If you run through all items in a set, using that indexing, you get quadratic total time. That's a good reason to not do it.

---

For the code shown, note that

```
if(i <= (this->size()-1)
```

doesn't handle size 0 well. In this case you get unsigned wrap-around so that the condition is `true`. Dereferencing the end iterator is then Undefined Behavior.

Comment: "*Indexing should never be more than logarithmic time, that's what's expected.*" Actually, what's expected is *constant time*. The Range TS even codifies this by declaring that Random Access Ranges provide `operator[]` support, that this function be O(1).

Comment: @NicolBolas: Those expectations are not incompatible. In some cases it can be reasonable with a logarithmic time indexing operator. The most common example is the indexing operator of `std::map`.

Answer (score 4):

The std::set doesn't generally have an efficient way to access the nth element.  The method you are using will start at the beginning of the set and advance one element at a time until it gets to the nth.  This would be very slow for large sets.

If you need it, then by all means do it, but`be aware of the inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from efficiency issues already mentioned, `std::set` (as most of the other standard containers) is not designed to be inherited from - especially, it does not provide a virtual destructor, so the following is bound to fail:

```
std::set<MyType>* s = new sset<MyType>();
delete s;
```

Sure, there should be little reasons for having a set created this way, but the issue still remains...

If you *really, really* need `n`th element and don't want to rewrite your sample code all the time, I'd rather have a separate function for than (at least) questionable inheritance:

```
template <typename T>
T& at(std::set<T>& s, size_t index)
{
    if(i < s.size())
        return *std::next(s.begin(), index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index is out of range");
}
template <typename T>
T const& at(std::set<T> const& s, size_t index)
{
    if(i < s.size())
        return *std::next(s.begin(), index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index is out of range");
}
```

Don't ever use that in a for loop iterating from 0 to size, use iterators instead or preferably a range based loop (which actually maps to a loop using iterators).